# Sending variable to other page with ajax (jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

ajax1.php

```
<input type="button" id="goal" />

<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>

$('#goal').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax2.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:123},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
            window.location.href = 'ajax2.php';
        },
        error: function() {
            alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
        }

    });
});

</script>
```

How i am gonna handle this `data: {id:123}` from ajax2.php?

Plus i want to ask how i am gonna send the variable(which i am gonna get inside ajax2.php) back to ajax1.php again.

Comment: Try this inside ajax2.php **after the php tag:** $id = $_POST['id']; var_dump($id); die();

Comment: @Dan-LeviTømta tried it. it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can access parameters in your ajax2.php through the `$_POST['id']` and then in your php you can echo your result back.

If you need to return more than one value you can create a JSON object and then in your success callback you can parse the JSON to manipulate the data

PHP

```
<?php
  if ($_POST['id'] == 123) {
    echo "Found"; 
  }
  else {
    echo "Missing"
  }
?>
```

jQuery

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data == "Found") {
    alert("Record was found");
  }
}
```

Comment: can you look my jsfiddle where i do a mistake?

Comment: Your JSFiddle is blank did you forget to update the url?

Comment: in ajax2.php it says  Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\ajax2.php on line 2

Comment: It saying because you are redirecting user after request success ... Remove window.location from success callback and use data as @rafa said .. It will be work fine.. Dont access ajax2.php directly because id is undefined if you access it directly . .. Or use if(isset($_POST['id']) condition to avoid from error

Comment: In your `$.ajax` change the `data` part to `data: {'id' : 123}`

Comment: @ZebiRajpot but i should use id variable  in ajax2.php. am i already getting iT?

Comment: if you call ajax2.php directly, as in type it into address bar, you will get undefined `$_POST['id']` because you didn't pass any data to it. With the `$.ajax` call you are passing that value.

Comment: In your success callback you are calling ajax2.php again but without that data so you will get undefined as well. Not really sure why you would want to call it twice either way so just handle the result from the first call in the success function.

Comment: @user3301042 Yes you are getting id through $.ajax so you no need to redirect user to ajax2.php ...